# Simplex interval analysis

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

In one dimension a real number can be constrained by two real numbers x in [a,b] or (a,b). In n-dimensions an n-dimensional point can be constrained by an (open) or [closed] simplex with n+1 vertices. I imagine it would usually be more useful to use an n-dimensional ball or cuboid for higher-dimensional interval analysis rather than a simplex, but can you give examples of where a simplex-interval would be used.

Comment: Not a research question.

Answer (score 2):

A typical operation is an affine transformation. The set of simplices is preserved by this, the set of balls is not.